# Password stored in SharedPreferences not working in android?

Tags: android

In this order, this is the procedure I'd like to implement.

1) When imageButton is pressed, it checks the value of "pass" stored in SharedPreferences. If this matches the password, the intent starts the next activity.

2) If it is null, or does not match the password, a dialog box pops up prompting username and password entry.

3) If the entered password is correct, it writes the username and password to SharedPreferences.

4) If the entered password is incorrect, it makes a Toast indicating as such.

Thus far, the login is working perfectly. However, I can't seem to get the SharedPreferences function to work. My code is below:

```
Button aliaLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    aliaLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("testapp", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("username","7");
            editor.putString("pass","11");
            editor.commit();
            String username = prefs.getString("username",null);
            String pass = prefs.getString("pass",null);
            if (pass != null && !pass.isEmpty() && pass.equals(housePass[5])){
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayHouse.class);
                intent.putExtra("Username", username);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else {

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(HouseMain.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Login Required!");
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login_toast);
                dialog.show();

                final EditText name = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.name);
                final EditText password = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.password);
                Button submit = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
                Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);

                submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        String username = name.getText().toString();
                        String pass = password.getText().toString();
                        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("testapp", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

                        if (pass.equals(housePass[5])) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayHouse.class);
                            intent.putExtra("Username", username);
                            editor.putString("username", username);
                            editor.putString("pass", pass);
                            editor.commit();
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect! Impostor alert!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        dialog.cancel();

                    }

                });
                cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }

                });

            }


        }
    });
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is this ` housePass[5] ` ?

Comment: why you are setting preference each time when the button is clicked ?

Comment: @RaviRupareliya It's the correct password.

Comment: @VividVervet Good point, let me try changing that.

Comment: It looks like that you are store hard coded values (username = "7" and password = "11" each time the imagebutton clicked). and then you compare the password to some value which stored in housePass array at position 5 I just need to clarify if this is really the code that you wanted to post or you post it with some test that you did in order to see if it works..

Comment: @VividVervet thank you! I've removed the code which sets preference every time the button is clicked, and now it works perfectly!

Comment: @RanHassid, yup that was it. VividVervet pointed out the problem.

Comment: @TheveshTheva I've answered :) , may be you can accept

Comment: Cool ! anyway the best practice is not to store password in the shared preferences but use some generated token you can read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#UserData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is each time when you click on the button you are resetting the user name and password to default

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("testapp", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("username","7");
        editor.putString("pass","11");
        editor.commit();
```

you have to remove it from your code

Comment: sorry, didn't see this or I'd have accepted it for sure! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have override pass save to Preference file with other pass:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("testapp", MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
 editor.putString("username","7");
 editor.putString("pass","11");
 editor.commit();
```